# UIbutton(Any)の表示・非表示設定

Tags: swift, ios, xcode

## 環境

swift3
Xcode9.0.1

## 内容

Storyboard内に用意したボタンを特定の条件下で表示/非表示にしたいのですが

`@IBAction func button(_ sender: Any){

   処理...

}`
と定義したボタンを"viewDidLoad"内で
`button.isEnable = false`
としてもエラーが出てしまいます。

この"button"を非表示にする方法を教えてください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

表示/非表示にしたいのであれば、

```
button.isEnable = false
```

ではなく

```
button.isHidden = true
```

でうまくいかないでしょうか？

Comment: 試しにやってみたのですが、"Value of type '(Any) -> ()' has no member 'isHidden'"というエラーが出てしまいました。

Comment: 変数 `button` に UIButton がセットされていないようですね。ボタンはStoryBoardで作っているでしょうか？ `@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!` のように定義していますか？

Comment: 定義をしたら思うように動作しました。